# Expect change numbers to names

Tags: linux, expect

Hi i'm firefighter and we have in Poland stqc modulation to active alarm  over radio on the firestations. My question is how to use expect to show name of station. Example: i run multimon-ng, signal os decoded and output is e.x 12345678.
I want that expect change this numbers to name of station e.g OSP XXX. And waiting for other input.im amateur in expect.
Sorry for my english. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Bubeqq - I read that multimon-ng is a program to decode radio transmissions. You seem to want to process its output. Why do you want to _use expect_ for that? And how should _expect_ or any other program know which _name of station_ corresponds to _12345678_?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.